# how to get text from .doc file using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pythonanywhere, .doc

I am extracting text from .docx file using following code

```
def getText(filename):
              doc = docx.Document(filename)
              fullText = []
              for para in doc.paragraphs:
                  fullText.append(para.text)
              return '\n'.join(fullText)
          data = getText(file_path)
```

Now,I want to extract .doc file also in my django rest api hosted on pythonanywhere.As api is on pythonanywhere I am unable to install textract library and antiword.So,How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

abiword is installed on PythonAnywhere:

```
abiword --to=txt myfile.doc
```

will produce a file called myfile.txt.

Comment: I got following error when I tried to run the command in virtual environment.
`** (abiword:26945): WARNING **: clutter failed 0, get a life.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.`

Comment: Try setting the environment variable XDG_RUNTIME_DIR to /tmp -- eg. from bash use `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp/` or if you're calling it from Python code, set it in the call you use to start it.

Comment: how to run the command in python script. `subprocess.call('abiword --to=txt _file_path')` is giving following error `Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: first you need to use the full path to abiword. On PythonAnywhere it's /usr/bin/abiword. Also, the argument to subprocess.call is not a string, it's a list. Check the documentation

Comment: Thanks for the help